# Error while mapping shared library sections: libhmmm.so: Success

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I'm having trouble with gdb and loading debugging information from shared libraries.

The error I get when running from within gdb is:

```
>>run
Error while mapping shared library sections: libhmmm.so: Success.
....
....
>>break container_main
Error cannot access memory at 0x9f18
```

The shared library in question exists and is located in the same directory, it contains debugging information and is not stripped.
The application works as expected.

When issuing **info sharedlibrary** from within gdb all shared libraries are listen but the **from** and **to** data is missing for the shared library in question.

Searched but haven't found any solution.

Comment: I'm getting DNS error on infoqu.com, is this link correct?

Answer (score 0):

Googling turned up an [old bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=127274) and a [forum discussion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?postid=975227) about some similar issue. If you are running GDB version < 6.1 then try upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: I'm running gdb 6.5 and it's this particular application + associated shared libraries that are giving me trouble, other applications seem to work fine.